Как вставить дискорд аватарку в ImageOpen?
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx, member:discord.Member = None):
    from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageOps, ImageFilter
    import io
    from io import BytesIO
    if member == None:
        member = ctx.author
    url = member.avatar.url
    img1= Image.open('avatar.png').resize((514, 470)).convert('RGBA')

У меня есть такой код. Как можно выставить url аватарки в имедж опен?

Если я вас правильно понял, вам нужен аватар в виде файла. Его можно получить через requests:
import requests
response = requests.get(ctx.author.avatar.url)
with open("avatar.png", "wb") as file:
    file.write(response._content)


Спасибо большое
